# How to fix ld-linux.so.2 error manually

Tags: linux, cmake, redhat, glibc, rhel6

I was trying to use cmake 3.0.0 to install the GROMACS in one of our servers and it yielded an error:

```
-bash: /root/cmake-3.0.0-Linux-i386/bin/cmake: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

As I found over the internet, it is probably due to the absence of glibc.i686. Somehow, our server is not registered in the subscription manager and I am unable to use `yum install` to solve the problem.

Any idea on how can I fix this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea on how can I fix this manually?

Yes: download the `glibc.i386` package appropriate for your system and manually install it. Probably something like `sudo rpm -iv glibc-2.x.y-i386.rpm` would do.